# React error invalid hook & state is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-hooks, state

I'm having an error while trying to make a modal. I tried to make a modal that appears when a button is clicked. It's a form that pops up in modal and after submitting it the modal closes.
The form was a regular component until I changed the flow so I changed the component to make it a modal.
After doing that I'm getting this error.

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

And also my state doesn't function anymore

```
 Line 7:4:  'state' is not defined  no-undef
```

It might be good to mention that I'm still pretty new to React.

This is the form that I made into a modal:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Mutation } from 'react-apollo'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap'

const CreateService = () => {
   state = {
    name: '',
    cost: '',
  }

  const { name, cost } = this.state
  const POST_MUTATION = gql`
 mutation PostMutation($cost: String!, $name: String!) {
  postService(cost: $cost, name: $name) {
    id
    cost
    name
  }
}
    `

  return (
    <Modal
      size="lg"
      aria-labelledby="contained-modal-create-service"
      centered
    >
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">Create service</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <div className="flex flex-column mt3">
          <input
            className="mb2"
            value={name}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
            type="text"
            placeholder="A name for the service"
          />
          <input
            className="mb2"
            value={cost}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ cost: e.target.value })}
            type="text"
            placeholder="The service cost"
          />
        </div>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Mutation mutation={POST_MUTATION}
          variables={{ cost, name }}
          onCompleted={() => this.props.history.push('/')}>

          {postMutation =>
            <button onClick={postMutation}>Submit</button>
          }
        </Mutation>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  )

}

export default CreateService
```

And also this is the place where the button is that should activate modal

```
class Sidenav extends Component {
render() {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
    const [modalShow, setModalShow ]= React.useState(false)
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {authToken && (
          <div id="nav-container">
            <div id="nav-buttons">
              <button>Add new client</button>
              <button onClick={()=> setModalShow(true)}>Create new service</button>
              <CreateService show={modalShow} onHide={() => setModalShow(false) }/>
            </div>
            <div id="nav-logout">
              <div id="svg">
                <svg className="bi bi-box-arrow-in-right" width="1.5em" height="1.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8.146 11.354a.5.5 0 010-.708L10.793 8 8.146 5.354a.5.5 0 11.708-.708l3 3a.5.5 0 010 .708l-3 3a.5.5 0 01-.708 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 8a.5.5 0 01.5-.5h9a.5.5 0 010 1h-9A.5.5 0 011 8z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.5 14.5A1.5 1.5 0 0015 13V3a1.5 1.5 0 00-1.5-1.5h-8A1.5 1.5 0 004 3v1.5a.5.5 0 001 0V3a.5.5 0 01.5-.5h8a.5.5 0 01.5.5v10a.5.5 0 01-.5.5h-8A.5.5 0 015 13v-1.5a.5.5 0 00-1 0V13a1.5 1.5 0 001.5 1.5h8z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                </svg>
              </div>
              <div
                id="logout"
                onClick={() => {
                  localStorage.removeItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
                  this.props.history.push(`/Login`)
                }}
              >
                logout
          </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
export default withRouter(Sidenav)
```

Can anyone help me understand what is going wrong or maybe share past experiences that could fix the issue?

Comment: why did u write this.state on line 7?

Comment: Also try to use 3rd party library. F.e. I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal

Comment: I followed a graphql - react tutorial they wrote it the same way. Should i write line 7 in a different way? (still learning it all)

Comment: If u've got a class component you reference to state through this. if u use functional ones just use the hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using hooks inside class components :

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

Hooks can only be used with Function Components like `const MyComponent = () => {}`

In the class components you have to use `this.state` with `this.setState` as updater

Comment: So I should change `SideNav.js` to `const SideNav = () =>{}`